# How to ask for user input in nested loops?

Tags: c++, user-input, nested-loops

I was given the task of displaying Fibonacci numbers, but while asking the user how many number he/she would like to compute at a given time.

There was an example in the book they told me to refer. I figured a few lines of change in the code would produce the answer to my problem, but I'm having trouble understanding where I went wrong with this code.

```
int main()
{ 
    int NumsToCal = 5;

    cout << "How many numbers would you like to calculate?" << endl;
    cin >> NumsToCal;

    cout << " This program will calculate " << NumsToCal << " Fibonacci Numbers at a time" <<endl;

    int Num1 = 0, Num2 = 1;
    char WantMore = '\0';
    cout << Num1 << " " << Num2 << " " ;

    do 
    {
        for( int Index = 0; Index < NumsToCal; ++Index)
        {
            cout << Num1 + Num2 << " ";

            int Num2Temp = Num2;
            Num2 = Num1 + Num2;
            Num1 = Num2Temp;
        }
        cout <<  "Do you want more numbers (y/n)? " << endl;
        cin >> WantMore;

    } while (WantMore == 'y');

        cout << "Goodbye!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you welcome! :), if that is the answer please check as correct my answer @Ham

Answer (score 1):

Xsami is absolutely right. You only need to include one more line like:

```
cin>>NumstoCal;
```

Though it won't be bad to change the way you output stuff for a bit more clarity.

Here is my code:
https://ideone.com/BXREP9

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that you have to do is read `NumsToCal` again, and you have to do something like this after `cin >> WantMore;`

```
if ( WantMore == 'y' ) 
{
    Num1 = 0;
    Num2 = 1;
    cout << "How many numbers would you like to calculate?" << endl;
    cin >> NumsToCal;
    cout << Num1 << " " << Num2 << " " ;
}
```

This is my code: http://ideone.com/a8um5Z